# Nested try-with-resources vs single

Tags: java, nested, try-catch

So I came across some code and wondered what would be the difference between using nested try-with-resource statements and using a single try-with-resource with multiple resources?

```
 private void doEverythingInOneSillyMethod(String key)
      throws MyAppException
    {
      try (Connection db = ds.getConnection()) {
        db.setReadOnly(true);
        ...
        try (PreparedStatement ps = db.prepareStatement(...)) {
          ps.setString(1, key);
          ...
          try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            ...
          }
        }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new MyAppException("Query failed.", ex);
      }
    }
```

vs:

```
private void doEverythingInOneSillyMethod(String key)
        throws MyAppException {
    try (Connection db = ds.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = db.prepareStatement(...);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();) {

        db.setReadOnly(true);

        ps.setString(1, key);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new MyAppException("Query failed.", ex);
    }
}
```

are there any benefits with the former?

Comment: In this case, I can't see any and would prefer the later. However, **if** there were some operation that might be recovered within context (maybe a retry on a remote file download) then *maybe*...